# Awakening a thread by a queue

Tags: python, multithreading

I want my thread to sleep when a queue is empty and wake up only when a data is put in it. 
Should I use a condition object? I have never used this object before and I can't find a simple example in python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the queue object in question is bound to name `q`, just call `q.get()`: it will sleep patiently as long as the queue is empty, then return the queue's first item as soon as the queue is made non-empty by another thread executing a `.put(whatever)` on it.  While [the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/queue.html?highlight=queue#Queue.Queue.get) may not be stellarly clear about this, that's the *default* behavior of `.get()` when you call it without any argument, and indeed the most popular way for a thread to read from a queue (which is why it was made the default in the first place;-).

Answer (score 0):

Pass `block=True` to [`Queue.get()`](http://docs.python.org/library/queue.html#Queue.Queue.get).

Comment: In the thread that is supposed to sleep, call the `get(block=True)` method of your `Queue` object. Then that method will not return until it has successfully gotten an object out of the queue.

Comment: this is the default behaviour of `Queue.get()`

Answer (score 0):

There's a nice Linux Gazette article online that has code using a condition variable you might find useful: http://linuxgazette.net/107/pai.html.  The article covers python threading in general.  Section 4.4, almost at the bottom, covers condition objects.